# Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options

Tags: node.js, express, express-session, connect-mongo

Below is my server.js file.I read documentation of connect-mongo and tried all but did not resolve my issue. I use mongodb compass and removed the connection code because they don't allowed me to insert extra code. Please help me

````
const app = express();
const MongoDbStore = require("connect-mongo");

// Session config

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    store: MongoDbStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_CONNECTION_URL,
    }),
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 },
  })
);```



**Here is the error which I am facing**.

Assertion failed: You must provide either mongoUrl|clientPromise|client in options
C:\Users\Tahmeed Ullah\Desktop\realtime-pizza\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119
            throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');
            ^

Error: Cannot init client. Please provide correct options
    at new MongoStore (C:\Users\Tahmeed Ullah\Desktop\realtime-pizza\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:119:19)     
    at Function.create (C:\Users\Tahmeed Ullah\Desktop\realtime-pizza\node_modules\connect-mongo\build\main\lib\MongoStore.js:136:16)    
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tahmeed Ullah\Desktop\realtime-pizza\server.js:37:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47



**Note**
I have remove connect-mongo and then re installed it. 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHAqb.png
````

Answer (score 1):

```
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo").default;


app.use(
  session({
    secret: "thisismysecret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoDbStore.create({
      mongoUrl: "mongodb://localhost:27017/pizza",
    }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 }, //cookie valid for 24 hours
  })
);
```